# Ramda: Remove empty object having dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ramda.js

I have this object where `addon_sizes` keys are dynamic i.e `"1","2", "3", "4"`:

```
const sizes = {
 "addon_sizes": {
        "1": ["a", "b"],
        "2": ["c"],
        "3": null,
        "4": []
    }
}
```

I need to remove all key/value pairs in this object where the value is null/undefined/empty array.

So the keys "3" and "4" should be removed from the list.

So far what i have tried is:

```
const newObj = R.reject(R.anyPass([R.isEmpty, R.isNil]))(sizes.addon_sizes);
```

But this doesn't remove the null or empty values.

Comment: i tested your code on a fiddle and it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new object by picking all properties that are not empty or nil:

```js
const { pickBy, complement, anyPass, isEmpty, isNil } = R

const fn = pickBy(complement(anyPass([isEmpty, isNil])))

const sizes = {"addon_sizes":{"1":["a","b"],"2":["c"],"3":null,"4":[]}}

const result = fn(sizes.addon_sizes)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged javascript:

You can iterate through the object entries and use the `delete` keyword to delete the negative or negative length properties.

```js
const sizes = {
    "addon_sizes": {
        "1": ["a", "b"],
        "2": ["c"],
        "3": null,
        "4": []
    }
};

Object.entries(sizes.addon_sizes).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
  if(!value || !value.length)
    delete sizes.addon_sizes[key];
});

console.log(sizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your definition of `remove`.  If you mean to mutate your original object, then Ramda will offer no help.  If you want to create a copy without those properties, your code already seems to work, although it still needs to be applied to your input object.  Here we do so with [`over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) and [`lensProp`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp)

```js
const cleanAddons = over (
  lensProp ('addon_sizes'), 
  reject (anyPass ([isNil, isEmpty]))
)

const sizes = { addon_sizes: {1: ["a", "b"], 2: ["c"], 3: null, 4: []}}

console .log (cleanAddons (sizes))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {over, lensProp, reject, anyPass, isNil, isEmpty} = R     </script>
```

`lensProp ('addon_sizes')` creates a `lens` which focuses on the `addon_sizes` property, and `over` uses that lens and your `reject`-based function to create a function that will create a copy of your original object with empty or nil values removed from the `addon_sizes`.

When using just two function, I find `either (f, g)` more semantic than `anyPass ([f, g])`, so I like this version slightly better, but it does the same thing:

```
const cleanAddons = over (
  lensProp ('addon_sizes'), 
  reject (either (isNil, isEmpty))
)
```